# Android: Listen to all toasts

Tags: android, toast

Is there a way to listen for toast messages created by other applications?

For context, my application broadcasts an intent to another application to toggle its services. The other application then issues a toast to say the service is now on or off. I want to intercept (just read) the toast messages after my broadcast to ensure I have toggled the service the correct way. Unfortunately I do not have any other way of knowing what current state the service is in outside of toggling it and waiting for toasts.

Thanks.

Comment: Just wondering if that is fact or assumption (no rudeness intended).

Comment: It's a fact, I've looked at the Android Source Code, unless you're planning to make your own version of Android, that won't be possible. You can't hook onto the Toast. But there are other methods of interacting with the service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Eventually I am planning on making my own version of android, but for now i am settling on pushing the limits of applications within the bounds of existing device roms. I have now looking as well, and cannot find anything to the contrary to your review. To solve the problem I found the open source version of what I needed to control and forked my own version that allows for control and messaging using broadcast receivers. Thank G-D for open source, and thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, i know for sure in 4.x

Hook into accessibility api, examples of text to speech are all around the net, but instead of hooking touches and stuff, you hook with the following:

```
AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED;
```

ive yet to figure out how to read only toasts, or notifications in the new systems, perhaps you can find a way to.

Comment: This works. If you know the text you are looking for its a quick way of listening to the toast stack. With multilingual options it's tough to rely on it however.

Comment: Mind to share the source? I need to listen to a toast from another activity, but am having a hard time navigating around the code required.

Answer (score 0):

try to extends AccessibilityService：

```
public class NotificationFetcherService extends AccessibilityService {

    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

    }
}
```

if you don't know how to use it,google will help you

Answer (score -1):

Per @st0le and my own review, its official that its not possible (ok, so technically it was not possible before either of us knew, but that's neither here or nor there).